# How can I return a column from CALCULATE function in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBI. I know how to use CALCULATE function like this.

```
measure = CALCULATE(
    sum(table[col1]),
    ALL('table'[col2]), 
    'table'[col3] = ...
)
```

However, let us say, I don't want to sum `table[col1]`, but want something like the following.

```
measure = CALCULATE(
    table[col1],
    ALL('table'[col2]), 
    'table'[col3] = ...
)
```

Basically I want to return all the filtered `table[col1]` rows. How can I do that? Is there some other function for such a thing?

Comment: CALCULATETABLE does what you want.

Comment: @RADO. Can you give an example on how to use it. I am trying to give table[col1] or 'table'[col1] as the first parameter, but it doesn't allow me to.

Comment: CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES(table[col1]), ....)  Keep in mind that DAX measures can usually return only scalar (single) value, and can't return multiple values. The only exception is when you use DAX to create new tables for your data model (similar to SQL use for queries or for data definitions). To get better advice, consider rewriting your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish.